# Increment field value on REPLACE

Tags: mysql

I have done this successfully with an UPDATE statement before but not a REPLACE.

I am saving favourite items in a mysql table when a user has checked out.

Table Favs is:

```
USER (int)
ITEM (int)
COUNT (int default 0)
```

The SQL I am trying is :

```
REPLACE INTO favs (user,item,count) VALUES ('1','3', count + 1)
```

although it does not throw any errors it does not seem to increment the value either.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't work like this on replace. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

> You cannot refer to values from the
>   current row and use them in the new
>   row. If you use an assignment such as
>   SET col_name = col_name + 1, the
>   reference to the column name on the
>   right hand side is treated as
>   DEFAULT(col_name), so the assignment
>   is equivalent to SET col_name =
>   DEFAULT(col_name) + 1.

Edit:

However, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE might do what you're trying to accomplish:

```
INSERT INTO favs (user, item) VALUES (2, 3) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Comment: OK no worries I will do a seperate UPDATE statement immediately after. Thank you.

Comment: Please see my edit - is this what you're trying to do? If so, it would be safer and more efficient than separate replace and update statements.

Comment: yer that works great thanks except you need to remove 'SET' from the statement for it to work.